# Firebase Realtime Database - deleting a child node after specific time. Are there cloud functions for it?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing an android app with objects that I want to expire after a certain time automatically.  Even when the user closes out of the app and services.

Oh yeah, I've written code in background services to trigger and organize deleted objects and move them into other nodes, but I'd like to find out if this is possible strictly on the back end.

Any insight would be very helpful!

Thanks 
-T

Comment: No, but you can create a server and connect it with Firebase pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any special function for what you want.
You have to trigger it manually `java.time` utility of android/java might be useful for this. write a method which check the time of system and and when the desire time match with your function timing trigger the `postRef.remove` for firebase.

maybe this helps

```
if(java.time.LocalDateTime==urTimeForDelete){postRef.remove();}
```

Comment: I'm currently using CountDownTimer in a background service, which seems to do the trick on the client side.  Just hoping Firebase can feature something to write nodes on the backend eventually :/ thanks

Comment: @TJBlack31 this seems solution also...Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

As every Firebase project is backed with a Google cloud project you use [App engine Cron service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#cron) to get you job done.